# SQL Pivot Error - Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a pivot query and cannot seem to find where the error occurs. It looks good to me. I am trying to pivot my SUM(Amounts) by the month the transaction date is. The transaction date is in format of 2017-01-01. I feel like the error is in this area.

```
SELECT *
FROM(SELECT MONTH(dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionDate) AS DATEMONTH, dbo.bill_c_ChargeZone.ChargeZoneCode, dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.Amount
FROM dbo.bill_c_TransactionType
INNER JOIN dbo.bill_c_TransactionTypeGroup ON (dbo.bill_c_TransactionType.TransactionTypeGroupCode = dbo.bill_c_TransactionTypeGroup.TransactionTypeGroupCode)
INNER JOIN dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction        ON (dbo.bill_c_TransactionType.TransactionTypeCode = dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionTypeCode)
INNER JOIN dbo.bill_t_TripTicket           ON (dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.RunNumber = dbo.bill_t_TripTicket.RunNumber)
INNER JOIN dbo.bill_c_ChargeZone           ON (dbo.bill_t_TripTicket.ChargeZoneCode = dbo.bill_c_ChargeZone.ChargeZoneCode)
WHERE dbo.bill_t_TripTicket.CompanyCode = '105'
  AND dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-05-31'
  AND dbo.bill_c_TransactionType.TransactionTypeCode = 'INV') AS srctbl
PIVOT (SUM(Amount) FOR MONTH(srctbl.TransactionDate) IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) AS pvttbl;
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think the issue is in the alias in the pivot FOR is causing an issue. Try with only the column.

Comment: try to format your code. will be easier to read for us and will also help you in future to change your scripts, find bugs and much more

Comment: I need at least 2 columns, one for the aggregate and the other for the pivot. Removing the chargezone did not change the results - thank you Jacob H

Comment: Thanks Esteban - as you can see I am very new at this. DotNetMatt was kind enough to do so below.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably related to the parenthesis you have inside the PIVOT clause. The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT *
FROM
          (
                    SELECT
                              MONTH(dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionDate) AS DATEMONTH
                            , dbo.bill_c_ChargeZone.ChargeZoneCode
                            , dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.Amount
                    FROM
                              dbo.bill_c_TransactionType
                              INNER JOIN
                                        dbo.bill_c_TransactionTypeGroup
                              ON
                                        (
                                                  dbo.bill_c_TransactionType.TransactionTypeGroupCode = dbo.bill_c_TransactionTypeGroup.TransactionTypeGroupCode
                                        )
                              INNER JOIN
                                        dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction
                              ON
                                        (
                                                  dbo.bill_c_TransactionType.TransactionTypeCode = dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionTypeCode
                                        )
                              INNER JOIN
                                        dbo.bill_t_TripTicket
                              ON
                                        (
                                                  dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.RunNumber = dbo.bill_t_TripTicket.RunNumber
                                        )
                              INNER JOIN
                                        dbo.bill_c_ChargeZone
                              ON
                                        (
                                                  dbo.bill_t_TripTicket.ChargeZoneCode = dbo.bill_c_ChargeZone.ChargeZoneCode
                                        )
                    WHERE
                              dbo.bill_t_TripTicket.CompanyCode = '105'
                              AND dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-05-31'
                              AND dbo.bill_c_TransactionType.TransactionTypeCode = 'INV'
          )
          AS srctbl PIVOT SUM(Amount) FOR MONTH(srctbl.TransactionDate) IN ([1]
                                                                          , [2]
                                                                          , [3]
                                                                          , [4]
                                                                          , [5]) AS pvttbl
;
```

Comment: I think your on to something DotNetMatt. I change this line to: `PIVOT SUM(srctbl.Amount) FOR MONTH(srctbl.TransactionDate) IN ([1]
                                                                          , [2]
                                                                          , [3]
                                                                          , [4]
                                                                          , [5]) AS pvttbl` and get this error now: Incorrect syntax near 'SUM'

Comment: I apologize my code is not tagged correctly for the comment but the back tick did not work for me. Is there another way I do this?

Comment: I think you're good with the code formatting in the comment. What if you fully qualify the column name in SUM? Like this: ``SUM(dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.Amount)``

Comment: No change in the error - I tried all the combinations to fully qualify one or both the aggregate and FOR with "dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction." or the subquery "srctbl"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the column TransactionDate in your subquery (srctbl)

In your pivot statement you have:

```
FOR MONTH(srctbl.TransactionDate)
```

Think you mean this instead:

```
FOR MONTH(srctbl.DATEMONTH)
```

Comment: TransactionDate is the first column in the subquery, ie MONTH(dbo.bill_t_ARTransaction.TransactionDate) AS DATEMONTH. I have tried using srctbl for both the SUM and MONTH functions with no change in error

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - Thank you to "all" for your help. It turned out to be a few things. There was a parenthesis missing after the word "Pivot" which changed the error from a "near (" to the word "near SUM" when DotNetMatt was nice enough to fix my syntax. The second part VDK and DotNetMatt kind of found together. I needed to fully qualify my columns using the correct query columns. The new line now:

```
AS srctbl PIVOT (SUM(srctbl.Amount) FOR srctbl.DATEMONTH IN ([1]
                                                                          , [2]
                                                                          , [3]
                                                                          , [4]
                                                                          , [5])) AS pvttbl;
```

Works great now! Again thank you all.